# C++ truncating when casting to smaller types

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, bit-fields

I have a 64-bit long int with some bitfields packed into it. I need a take a 16-bit signed int stored in the second and third bytes and add it to a 32-bit value. I'm using something like this:

```
u32 Function( s32 value , u64 bitfield )
{
    return value + (s16) (bitfield >> 8)
}
```

Can I rely on the compiler to cast the bitfield to a 16-bit signed int before it expands it to a 32-bit signed int and performs the addition? If not, how else should I truncate the remaining bytes and perform the type conversion I require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with the caveat that you're relying on compiler- and architecture-specific behavior. Of course, relying on this behavior will lead you into really difficult-to-diagnose "features" (bugs).

You're probably better off writing out (telling the compiler) what you want specifically, letting the optimization pass and other passes eliminate the unnecessary code:

```
u32 Function(s32 value, u64 bitfield)
{
  // Extract 16 bit qty from 64-bit: (x|x|x|x|x|1|2|x), preserving
  // signedness
  return value + (s32) (((bitfield << 40) >> 48) & 0xffffffff);
}
```

(Yes, putting a comment there would also help future maintainers.)

Comment: While this solution truncates the unwanted information, it doesn't preserve the sign of the 16 bits. I'd considered using something like:
return value + ( (s32) bitfield << 8) >> 16);
While I believe this would work, I find it startlingly ugly.

Comment: Ok, fair point that you wanted to preserve signedness. However, despite the "ugly", it is clear what your intentions are (bit extraction) and preserves signedness. Let the compiler do the hard work of selecting the appropriate instructions. Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Updated to preserve signedness and keeping operations on `bitfield` as `u64` until absolutely necessary.